# How to break date values in Jquery UI date picker?

Tags: jquery, parsing, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I have some things to do, but is bit complicated for me.I need some help from you guys.
 Here is the thing, I set Jquery UI date picker on first input field with id of day, but date values I get--> 03/02/2011 should be parsed on three  input fields in particular format? see code below:

```
<label>Enter Day of Arrival (in the format DD) 
<input type="text" name="$DAY$" id="day" size="6" maxlength="6" /> 

<label>Enter Month of Arrival (in the format MM) 
<input type="text" name="$MONTH$" id="month" size="6" maxlength="6" /> 

<label>Enter Year of Arrival (in the format YYYY) 
<input type="text" name="$YEAR$" id="year" size="6" maxlength="6" />>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've coded an example on fiddle. Code below

```
<input type='text' id='full' name='fulldate'>
<!-- Your other HTML fields listed above -->

$('#full').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var pieces = dateText.split('/');
        $('#day').val(pieces[0]);
        $('#month').val(pieces[1]);
        $('#year').val(pieces[2]);
    }
})
```

**Example : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/7NgpQ/**

Comment: Thx JohnP!

Great!

Is there any way to do this like you did it, but to not show fields for day, month, year?To hide it from users, but that values to work in back like they should.I hope that question is not confusing.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Instead of `type='text'` simply set it to `type='hidden'` and it will disappear from view. Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: Sorry, first time on stack. how to mark answer as accepted...Thx this deff solve my problem! I got one more question if is not to much?Got issues with z- index and internet explorer behavior with same date picker.If you will take a look on [link](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk) if not thx anyway, you help me a lot.

Comment: No problem, just click on the green checkmark below the up and down arrows. You can use the arrows to vote up or down depending on whether the answer was useful. See the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq . As for your question, put `.ui-datepicker  {z-index:1000!important}` in your CSS and it should fix the problem for you.

Comment: That code in your CSS should work for everything. You might be better off posting a new question with examples and that code included.

Comment: @JohnP datepicker work well, but one important issue make me serious problems.Problem is when user dont select date from datepicker and submit query, external service throw error, otherwise everything is ok.
How to prevent that, disable submit button if date is not selected?Any ideas onhow to do that.

I put code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/6Pcm9/5/)

One more question.How to prevent users to select previous date than tommorow date and set tommorow as default date>

thx

Comment: @user642523 you should create a new question or search SO for existing answers